# Prometheus Alert Manager not sending out alerts

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-alertmanager

I am working with Prometheus on Kubernetes and trying to send out the alerts to slack. The problem is that the alert is firing but is not getting sent out to slack.
I am using Prometheus 1.18.1 with Kubernetes 1.9.

For now I am just trying to send out the ‘DeadMansSwitch’ alert which is built-in and I can see in UI that it is firing. My alertmanager.yaml (under prometheus-operator/contrib/kube-prometheus/assets/alertmanager) looks like this:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
  slack_api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/AAABBBCCC/DDDEEEFFF/GGGHHHIII’
route:
  group_by: ['job']
  group_wait: 1s
  group_interval: 1s
  repeat_interval: 1s
  receiver: ‘slack’
  routes:
  - match:
       alertname: DeadMansSwitch
    receiver: ‘slack’
receivers:
- name: ‘slack’
   slack_configs:
   - channel: ‘#channel-name’
```

The config on the AlertManager UI shows this:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
  smtp_require_tls: true
  pagerduty_url: https://events.pagerduty.com/v2/enqueue
  hipchat_api_url: https://api.hipchat.com/
  opsgenie_api_url: https://api.opsgenie.com/
  wechat_api_url: https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/
  victorops_api_url: https://alert.victorops.com/integrations/generic/20131114/alert/
route:
  receiver: "null"
  group_by:
  - job
  routes:
  - receiver: "null"
    match:
      alertname: DeadMansSwitch
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 12h
receivers:
- name: "null"
templates: []
```

Questions:
- The config on the AlertManager UI is different from what I have in the alertmanager.yaml file. Where is this config (in UI) coming from?
- Is setting receivers in alertmanager.yaml not enough to send out alerts? Am I missing anything here?
- Am I making changes in the wrong yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr = that yaml is so malformed that I'm stunned it parsed at all.

---

It's caused by two bits of invalid YAML: the indentation and the use of "smart apostrophes"; You have:

```
receivers:
- name: ‘slack’
   slack_configs:
```

but it should be:

```
receivers:
- name: 'slack'
  slack_configs:
```

otherwise in YAML it makes `name` into an **object** with a property of `slack_configs` rather than an anonymous object containing two properties `name` and `slack_configs`

Every place you have a "quoted" string of `slack` in your posted config, you have used the smart apostrophes which from YAML's point-of-view makes the string literal as `"\u2018slack\u2019"` instead of what you meant (it's a separate question why you quoted the string to begin with, since it's not any different from `5m` or `DeadMansSwitch`).

You also have a normal ascii apostrophe leading the `slack_api_url:` but a smart apostrophe closing that string.

The infinitely handy [remarshal](https://github.com/dbohdan/remarshal#readme) project contains `yaml2json` which is great for spotting weird YAML-isms like that